# Damped Harmonic Oscillator $2y''+8y'+8y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Underdamped Harmonic Oscillator $2y''+8y'+8y=0$

I am given mass $m=2$, damping coefficient $b=8$ and spring constant $k=8$

I first need to change this into a first order system so I get:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = v$ and $\frac{dv}{dt} = -4y - 4v$ so if I change this into matrix form:

$$ \frac{dY}{dt} = \Bigg(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -4 & -4 \end{array} \Bigg) Y$$

My question now is it fine to solve this by using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors? I only ask because we previously solved it differently in class.

Comment: Since $b \neq 0$, this system is *underdamped*, not undamped.

Comment: Critically damped.

Comment: A non-math response to "is it fine to solve this by using the eigenvalues" is to ask your instructor.  I've been in classes that allowed calculators and the professor didn't care if I had it invert a $6 \times 6$ system and others wanted the steps written down. I've been in an engineering class where I was explicitly forbidden from using two-dimensional integrals despite having learned them because they were not part of the prerequisite material. So despite the correctness of the math, I'd say ask the instructor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is easier to use this approach.  You could just say the characteristic equation is
$2r^2 + 8r + 8 = 0\\
2(r+2)^2 = 0\\
y = C_1  e^{-2t} + C_2 t e^{-2t}\\
$

Anyway, if you want to keep going with the approach you have chosen.

$det(A - \lambda I) = 0\\
\lambda^2 - trace(A) \lambda + det(A) = 0\\
\lambda^2 +4 \lambda + 4 = 0\\ 
(\lambda + 2)^2 = 0\\
$

Doesn't that look familiar.

$(A - \lambda I)v = \begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\-4&-2\end{pmatrix}v = 0\\
v = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-2\end{pmatrix}$

we have one eigenvector.  When we have duplicated eigenvectors we look for some $w$ such that

$(A - \lambda I)w = v\\
w = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

will suffice.

$Y = C_1 v e^{-2t} +  C_2(v t e^{-2t} + w e^{-2t})\\
Y(0) = C_1 v+C_2 w = \begin{pmatrix} C_1\\-2C_1 + C_2\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} y(0)\\y'(0)\end{pmatrix}\\
C_1 = y(0), C_2 = y'(0) - 2y(0)\\
y(t) = y(0) e^{-2t} - 2y(0) t e^{-2t} + y'(0) t e^{-2t}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of the Matrix of coefficients. Then find the eigenvectors $v_i$ associated with each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. The solution of your system is (if you have two different eigenvalues).

$$Y=c_1v_1e^{\lambda_1t}+c_2v_2e^{\lambda_2t}$$

if they are not the same, you will have to calculate your second vector by the following ansatz:

$Y=(a+bt,c+dt)^Te^{\lambda_1t}$

Comment: "if you have two different eigenvalues" Precisely, they have not...

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot y\\\dot v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-4&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\v\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}y\\v\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=\lambda^2+4\lambda+4=(\lambda+2)^2=0$$
If $\lambda=-2$, then
$$A-\lambda I=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-4&-2\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{\text{R}_2-2\text{R}_1}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
So an eigenvector belonging to $\lambda=-2$ is
$$\vec v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we want a solution of the form $\vec x=\vec v_1te^{\lambda t}+\vec v_2e^{\lambda t}$. The differential equation says that $(\lambda\vec v_1+\vec v_1+\lambda\vec v_2)e^{\lambda t}=(A\vec v_1+A\vec v_2)e^{\lambda t}=(\lambda\vec v_1+A\vec v_2)e^{\lambda t}$, so we have to solve $(A-\lambda I)\vec v_2=\vec v_1$
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\-4&-2&-2\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{\text{R}_2-2\text{R}_1}\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
So we have freedom to choose $\vec v_2$ if we want an orthogonal vector our solution would be
$$\vec v_2=\begin{bmatrix}2/5\\1/5\end{bmatrix}$$
So our general solution is
$$\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}e^{-2t}+\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}x+\frac15\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)e^{-2t}$$